# Laravel 4.2 form action not working

Tags: laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and am building a simple web application. I'll show what code I'm using next and then I'll explain my problem.

Here's how my form starts in the view `login.blade.php`:

```
<?php
        //build the form
        echo Form::open(array('action' => 'AuthenticationController@authenticateUser'));
```

And here's what the route for the home page:

```
  Route::get('/', function() {
        return View::make('login', array('page_title' => 'Log in to MANGER'));
 });
```

Finally, here's the authentication controller (for now it's a simple redirect to simulate login):

```
class AuthenticationController extends BaseController {

    public function authenticateUser()
    {
        //retrive from database
        return View::make('hr', array('page_title' => 'MANGER Login'));
    }

}
```

My problem is, I'm getting an error on `login.blade.php`. saying: Route [AuthenticationController@authenticateUser] not defined. (View: /opt/lampp/htdocs/manger/app/views/login.blade.php)

How is the error about a route when I've defined a controller instead? And also, how can this be fixed? Please excuse any noob errors and thanks a lot in advance! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You still need to define your route like this:

```
Route::post('authenticate', ['uses' => 'AuthenticationController@authenticateUser']);
```

Otherwise it won't know what method to use, or the url to create.

Comment: What does 'authenticate' mean here? I'm not using any authentication for now, by the way; it's supposed to be just a simple redirect.

Comment: This will generate an url like this: http://host/authenticate (you can of course name it as you wish). I was just assuming that you will do a post on that page, as it is usually the case with forms.

Comment: It's actually a login form that will redirect to other pages. Will try your method and respond soon. Bye for now! :)